# Django & WORDPRESS

Tags: python, django

Hola soy nuevo acá quisiera saber si de alguna manera podría modificar el visual de mi un pequeño proyecto en el que estoy trabajando lo podría modificar desde Wordpress para no tener que ponerme hacer código de CSS. Saludos cordiales y gracias por su tiempo. Mi proyecto trata sobre una pequeña tienda que solo quisiera mostrar los productos que tienen en venta en esos momento en su tienda física para que los clientes puedan saber si lo que desean esta en esos momentos disponible, precio y que pueda dejar referencias de la calidad del producto.

Comment: Seria recomendarte WordPress entonces

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.